# Inconsistent behavior with similar code

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm quite newbie to xcode and objective-C and I'm quite confused because I'm getting different behavior on similar code. The code I'm talking about is:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KTSDetalleVisitaViewController *detailViewController = [[KTSDetalleVisitaViewController alloc] initForNewItem: NO withDelegate:self];

    NSArray *items = [[KTSVisitasStore sharedStore]allItems];
    Visita *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //Give detail view controller a pointer to the selected item
    [detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

    //Put the new detailViewController into the top of the navigation controller's stack
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    if (![self splitViewController]) {
        [nav setToolbarHidden:NO];
        [nav setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

        [nav setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
         NSArray *nvc = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self navigationController], nav, nil];

        [[self splitViewController] setDelegate:detailViewController];
        [[self splitViewController] setViewControllers:nvc];
    }
}
```

This code does what is supposed to do, I mean, it takes an element from a NSArray that matches with the selected row in a TableViewController and put the element in a DetailedViewController which is shown in a separate view (depending on the device type). As I said, this code works perfectly.

On another class I have this similar code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    KTSDetalleArticuloViewController *detailViewController = [[KTSDetalleArticuloViewController alloc] initForNewItem: NO withDelegate:self];

    NSArray *items = [[KTSArticuloStore sharedStore]allItems];
    Articulo *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    //Give detail view controller a pointer to the selected item
    [detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

    //Put the new detailViewController into the top of the navigation controller's stack
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                   initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    if (![self splitViewController]) {
        [nav setToolbarHidden:NO];
        [nav setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

        [nav setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        NSArray *nvc = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self navigationController], nav, nil];

        [[self splitViewController] setDelegate:detailViewController];
        [[self splitViewController] setViewControllers:nvc];
    }
}
```

Which is supposed to do exactly the same the previous code does, but it doesn't. The problem is that the method viewDidLoad is launched before the invocation of setViewControllers and is in that method (viewDidLoad) where I set the information on the UI from the object retrieved from the NSArray.

I both detailViewControllers *item object is declared as weak and nonatomic variable, and implemented using synthesize statement.

I already check that a not nil object is retrieved, so it's obvious that I must missing something in the lifecicle of the DetailViewController.

Any advice will be very welcomed. Thanks in advance for your help guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called on your `alloc] init` line.
You have 2 options to make this work.

1, You can change the init method and add another parameter to it, like

```
KTSDetalleArticuloViewController *detailViewController = [[KTSDetalleArticuloViewController alloc] initForNewItem: NO withSelectedItem:selectedItem withDelegate:self];
```

then grab the `selectedItem` and set it to the instance variable so `viewDidLoad` can use it.

2, You can move your UI code from `viewDidLoad`
 to `viewWillAppear` as this won't be called until it's added to the view.

Comment: your answer works perfectly but why this code behaves differently in both cases. I agree, before reading your answer, that putting the code to update the UI in the viewDidLoad is not the right place, but why this worked differently? I mean, first code always updated correctly the UI but seconds doesn't.

Comment: Without seeing all your code I can't really say why it works then doesn't. My guess would be that you refresh the UI at some point in the first instance but not the 2nd.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I'm gonna review my code and search for this kind of refresh. Thanks again for your help